# How to call a method in vuejs on post load?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, html-framework-7

I would like to call a method in vuejs, like after page load with all plugins. I'm trying to call like this,

```
mounted: function mounted() {
          this.callToLoggedUser();
        },
```

when i try to do like this f7 instance got undefined. Because of calling a method inside the mounted there is no chance for f7 to load before, but after calls by onclick f7 instance is working properly.

```
callToLoggedUser() {
f7.mainView.router.load({url: '/welcome/'});
}
```

How to call a method after f7 initialization?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When mounted is called, the DOM is not ready. You should try using nextTick to call after the DOM Operations have been done:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced

```
 mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.callToLoggedUser();
  })
}
```

or if you only want to call one function you can use a shorter syntax

```
 mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(this.callToLoggedUser)
}
```